# What are valid id and name attribute values in HTML?

Tags: html

Recently I ran into a problem with HTML that took me a while to figure out. 
HTML is not case sensitive, but it turns out that the values of id and name attributes are case sensitive.

This made me wonder what else do I need to know. Are there any other rules about id and name values?

Comment: because `Javascript and Jquery` is case sensitive

Comment: Depends on the version of HTML, but the place to look is in the relevant docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Tag names and attributes are not case sensitive, attribute *values* are.